# SSH Daemon does not autostart

Tags: server, ssh, services, autostart

I use a VPS with Ubuntu 10.04. After I performed "apt-get upgrade", the ssh daemon stopped working and does not automatically start when I restart my server. I have only access to files (edit, create delete etc.) and no shell access. Could you please help me out with setting up SSH Daemon autostart? Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe this could be handy: http://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/06/sshd-not-running-at-startup

Comment: What happens when you type `sudo invoke-rc.d ssh start` from the console of the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH Server stops working after reboot, caused by missing /var/run/sshd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/init.d/rc.local` and add to the bottom:

```
sshd &
```

Then restart the server.

Comment: This is definitly not the standard solution. I think it would be better to find out why the daemon does not automatically start.