# SSH Daemon doesn't start normally way

Tags: server, ssh, autostart

I use Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS (Kernel 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64).
And Install openssh-server(1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1).
At first, I use below.

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh.service
```

But sshd doesn't start in boot process.
So, I check this Questions -> ([SSH Daemon does not autostart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101881/ssh-daemon-does-not-autostart))
And try this article -> (http://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/06/sshd-not-running-at-startup)
However, sshd doesn't start. (`sudo service ssh status` is dead.)
Of course, I check symbolic link of `/etc/rc*.d/S**ssh` is created.

Then I added below to `/etc/rc.local`.

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
```

Finally, sshd does start on boot, but I wonder why normally process doesn't work.
It might be because using usb wireless adapter, but I cannot be sure that.
Please tell me what do you think.

Comment: I have no direct experience with this, but reading around it seems likely that the "right" approach is to tell sshd to start on `network-online.target` instead of `network.target` - see [Linux tip: Force systemd networkd to wait for DHCP](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/10/linux-tip-force-systemd-networkd-to-wait-for-dhcp.html) - but note that you are probably using NetworkManager not networkd - so the enable command would be `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` [Running Services After the Network is up](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/)

Comment: Thanks.
I didn't understand well about "ssh daemon needs specific IP."
I didn't set `ListenAddress ` of `sshd_config` . So I thought sshd doesn't need specific IP to start service. I thought device initialization is only needed by ssh daemon.

Comment: I tried `network-online.target` approach, but failed to start sshd. And I don't use NetworkManager, but networking daemon. This may be because of version of systemd. systemd message is 
`Dependency failed for Wait for Network to be Configured.
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Job systemd-networkd-wait-online.service/start failed with result 'dependency'`

Comment: I re-install "ubuntu server", and I checked option of "open-ssh" install in dialogue. This works well, and sshd is start automatically. After all, I don't understand cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure openssh-server is installed. If installed already try reinstalling as follows :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , there isn't any issue with 4.4 kernel and Linux kernel 4.6 is also compatible as well. If you still have the problem then I recommend you to upgrade your kernel or recompile your kernel.

Comment: I didn't write in question, but I already re-installed openssh-server. But nothing changed. No one else seems to have same problem, I think this is my environmental problem.

Comment: Linux image 4.6 don't seems to provide with `apt` . I think manually upgrade of linux kernel isn't recommended. I'm unwilling to.